# Doskey parameter as part of a string

Tags: windows, command-line

I would like to use $1 parameter from doskey command as part of a string (string interpolation, so to speak) but I get a space after the parameter and it breaks the string:

ie:

```
doskey test=command.exe my-string-with-$1-parameter
```

when I run the command

```
test unique
```

I get this

```
command.exe my-string-with-unique -parameter
```

instead of:

```
command.exe my-string-with-unique-parameter
```

is there anyway to inset the parameter in the string without the trailing space?

Thanks :).

Comment: This works fine in cmd.exe, perhaps you added space after "unique" or maybe this is related to you being on old version of Windows that has command.exe

Comment: thanks it seems like after some retries you were correct :)